# Am I authenticating correctly? How do I handle errors with RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

7I have a page that uses basic authentication. I am trying to authenticate it, but I keep getting a runtime error and I am not sure how to figure out how to debug it.

On my server, the page is SSL.  I try to create a rest client to another SSL page on the same domain. Is this  a problem?

```
var nclient = new RestClient();
nclient.BaseUrl = "https://www.blank.com/";
nclient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(id, password);
var nrequest = new RestRequest();
nrequest.Resource = "login.html";
nrequest.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");

IRestResponse response;
response = nclient.Execute(nrequest);

  if (response.ErrorException != null)
        {
            throw response.ErrorException;
        }
```

Error:

```
[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.190:443]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +251
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +279


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   WebApplication3._default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\\default.aspx.cs:40
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You haven't posted the error, you've posted a message telling you that you aren't being shown the error.  Follow its instructions to get the actual error, and then post *that*.

Comment: That's not an error, that's IIS saying there _was_ an error, but it won't tell you the specifics of it. You need to follow the instructions to see what the actual error was.

Comment: Either run the code on the local machine or follow the instructions in the message.

Comment: When I run the code on my local machine, it runs fine 100%. It dies on the published server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Turns out it I had to publish the page to a different server. It's working now.